# CSS list-style-image in Content Editor?

Tags: css, content-editor-web-part

Anybody ever successfully used list-style-image css property in a ul list embedded in a SharePoint Content Editor web part?

list-style-type works, but whenever I try to get an image instead of the boring bullets, SharePoint deletes this part from the web part's html source (in-line or not).

So, has anyone faced this before?

Comment: don't know the specifics of your problem but sometimes it's better to have a linked file in CEWP and implement your css externally without the hassle of page edit, checkin-checkout, edits being removed, etc.

Comment: Optionally you could give a try to a table layout. In the left column add the img and align it to top of the <td>.

Answer (score 0):

I think teylyn said it best

> this is a known issue, especially with wiki pages. Instead of entering
>   html and JavaScript directly into the CEWP (using the HTML edit
>   method), save the html and JavaScript in a text file. Upload that text
>   file to a document library on the site (or the Style Library of the
>   Site Collection, where the user will not be able to accidentally
>   delete it). Then edit the CEWP and at the top of the settings panel
>   enter the URL of the uploaded script file.
>
> This method has the added benefit that you can use the same script on
>   many pages. If you need to change the script, you only need to change
>   it in one place.
>
> Another benefit is that you can use version history in the library
>   where the script file is saved, so you have much better control when
>   developing new scripts.

[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/79a58b1b-c32d-40d4-a92c-05c79e5780e6/sharepoint-2010-deletes-the-htmlcss-code-i-input-on-the-web-editor-?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)